# Defining a constant datamember

Tags: c++, static, constants

Programe #1

```
// file.h
class File
{
public:
    static const int var = 9;
};
```

-

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "file.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    File f;
    cout << f.var;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Programe #2

```
// file.h
int GlobalVar ;
class File
{
public:
    static const int var = 9;
};
```

-

```
// main.cpp
extern int GlobalVar;

#include <iostream>
#include "file.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << GlobalVar;
    return 0 ;
}
```

---

Program#1 is running fine, but program#2 gives linker error:

```
error LNK2005: "int GlobalVar" (?x@@3HA) already defined in file.obj
```

I know the header files are never compiled. Then in the above case, how the compiler knows the definition of variable var, but not able to find the definition of `GlobalVar`?
What is the difference between this two programs?

Comment: What do you mean by "program#2 is not running fine"?

Comment: program#2 gives the linker error .

Comment: Please, provide the exact error message.

Comment: error LNK2005: "int GlobalVar" (?x@@3HA) already defined in file.obj

Comment: This is different thing, but see my edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use

```
#include "some_header.h"
```

or

```
#include <some_header.h>
```

these `include` directives are directly* replaced by the pre-processor with the content of `some_header.h`.

So, when you compile the `cpp` file, it actually includes the content of `some_header.h`. That's how this code is compiled.

<sub>* - if you have include guards, the content my be skipped, if it's already included by some other header</sub>

---

**EDIT:** Regarding your edit - about `extern`: this is not the correct way to do it.

```
extern int GlobalVar ;
```

should be placed in the **header**, and

```
int Globalvar ;
```

should be in the **cpp** file. You should read a little more about `extern` to understand how it works and what does it do (hint: suppose you want to have **only one** variable, defined at one place and reachable in multiple cpp files - how would you do it? There are plenty of questions in SO, too, about this case).

Comment: I know this is not the correct way to do . But to get clarification on my doubts i have posted the above code (program#2).
How far i know we have to define it in cpp files since to allocate the memory for it during compilation . since .h file never compiles we have to give definition for it inside cpp file . But this is not the case for program#1 . That is where i am getting doubt like for programe#1 also we have initialized  static variable inside .h file , hence it allocated some memory .As a result the programe#1 works fine . Then why dont it works in case of programe#2 ?

Comment: @viku - I think you need to read my answer again and more carefully. Both cases are absolutely identical - the **only** difference is the **wrong** usage of `extern`. You're right, that the headers are not compiled, BUT the code inside them **IS** compiled - as it replaces the `include` directives. You can test this by your own: 1. **Cut** the code from `file.h` from your second example; 2. **Replace** `include "file.h"` with the code from 1.; 3. Compile ONLY the `file.cpp` - you'll get **the same error**. Again - reason: wrong usage of `extern`. **Nothing** to do with header/cpp files.

Comment: @viku - actually, maybe you're missing something here by mistake - `GlobalVar` is **never** defined! What you have in your header is `Globalvar` (note the capital `V` in the `cpp` file)

Answer (score 0):

There is a certain allowance for static const data members which is similar to the allowance for inline functions (functions defined in the header file either within a class declaration or marked as inline). For static const data members of primitive types (e.g., integers), it is allowed to define them in the header file even if that would technically lead to One Definition Rule (ODR) violations, because for such primitive types and under the assumption that all instances of those data members seen by the linker came from the same header file, it is safe to assume that they will all be equal. And because they are constant, there is no problem in having many copies (or optimizing them away entirely), but if non-const, then there must be a guarantee of a single instance being manipulated. And because they are of primitive types (with trivial constructors), there are no issues of side-effects from the multiple construction of the static data member (in multiple translation units), but if non-primitive, then there must be a guarantee that the construction happens only once during the static initialization. So, obviously, this exceptional rule doesn't apply to static data members that are non-const and/or non-primitive (class type), in which case, they must be defined in one translation unit only (one compiled cpp file).